# Use jquery change function for all fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have made for myself input field price check numbers, dot and if comma then replace it to dot.

With change function I change comma to dot and use .toFixed(n)

I am trying to create one function so then I can call it from different inputs. It is not good idea to create for 20 input 20 change functions.

HTML:

```
<input id="txtId" type="text" onkeyup="NumAndTwoDecimals(event , this);"></input>
<br>
<input id="txtId2" type="text" onkeyup="NumAndTwoDecimals(event , this);"></input>
```

JS

```
    $('#txtId').change(function( event ) {

            var newVal = String($(this).val()).replace(/\,/g,'.');

            var regexp = /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;

            if (regexp.test(newVal)) {

                $(this).val(Number(newVal).toFixed(2));

            }else{
                // error
                $(this).val('');
            }
    });

window.NumAndTwoDecimals = function(e , field) {
    var val = field.value;
    var re = /^([0-9]+[\,||\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g;
    var re1 = /^([0-9]+[\,||\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)/g;
    if (re.test(val)) {
        //do something here
    } else {
        val = re1.exec(val);
        if (val) {
            field.value = val[0];
        } else {
            field.value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vaaZ/5/

Comment: Use `.each`... See here: [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: or [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 2):

YOu can give them a common classs and bind the event to that class.

Or you can use attribute starts with selector like this

```
$('[id^=txtId]').change(function( event ) {
```

This will bind change events to elements with id starts with `txtId`